# Bind raw markup to MVC action parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

A Report model has a following definition:

```
public class Report
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now, there is a JavaScript/jQuery code, which generates the following markup and add it to the form (on submit):

```
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="Description[0]" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="Name[0]" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="Order[0]" />

<input type="hidden" value="..." name="Description[1]" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="Name[1]" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="Order[1]" />

..
..


<input type="hidden" value="..." name="Description[n]" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="Name[n]" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="Order[n]" />
```

My action looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Reports(IEnumerable<Report> reports)
{
    // reports is null, even if I change the param type to: Report[] reports
}
```

I do not want to create a separate ViewModel for this, just need to change the raw markup, so it maps to parameter.

Also tried by changing the markup with `name="Reports[0].Order"`, `name="Reports[0].Name"` and so forth, but the values are not binding to action's parameter.

Is there a way to modify the markup and make the binding work, in such a way that we don't have to change anything in controller code (mimicking markup exactly how Razor would have generated)?

Comment: Your input elements needs to have unique identifier (`id`) for the model to post the values back to the controller.

Comment: Learn to use the strongly typed html helpers for rendering your markup for the model and inspect the html it generates, particularly for the `name` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="[0].Description" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="[0].Name" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="[0].Order" />

<input type="hidden" value="..." name="[1].Description" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="[1].Name" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="[1].Order" />

..
..


<input type="hidden" value="..." name="[n].Description" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="[n].Name" />
<input type="hidden" value="..." name="[n].Order" />
```

Comment: also, read this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) to understand all about mvc array binding